# how to compare password in passport-local-mongoose

Tags: node.js, passport.js, bcrypt, passport-local

I would like to compare a logged in user's password, with the password they provided from a form, because i need to make sure that it is really the user, cause i wish to provide an option for them to enable 2fa, and i believe anyone can enable that if the user is logged into the dashboard. Am using bcrypt to compare the password but it throws error.. also am using passport-local-mongoose for registering my users and for authentication.

```
router.post("/enableTwoFa/:id", isLoggedIn, isVerified, function(req, res){
if(req.isAuthenticated){
    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err,found){
    if(err){
        res.redirect("back")
        res.send('User not found with the proper ID')
    } else {
        if(req.body.accountPassword){
            console.log(found)
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.accountPassword,found.password, function(err,success){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                    res.send('There was a problem somewhere')
                } else {
                    console.log(success)
                    res.send('password hashed')
                }
            })

        } else {

                res.send('Please input your account password!!')
        }
    }
})
} else {
    res.send('You are not authorized for this request')
}

})
```

it throws up an error of missing data and hash. But i don't know how to find the required field.. or if there is a function that handles this in passport, am new to this.

```
Error: data and hash arguments required
    at Object.compare (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bit-main/main/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:209:17)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/bit-main/main/routes/dashboard.js:448:24
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bit-main/main/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3928:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/bit-main/main/node_modules/kareem/index.js:297:21
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/bit-main/main/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: Either the first or second parameter of the `bcrypt.compare` call is null or undefined. Are you sure that `found`  has a property named `password`?

Comment: @puelo thanks for noting that, am using passport.. so the password is not stored in the db rather it is the hash.. and also i do not find the hash in the found argument

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research on this question, i found out that there is an authenticate() function in passport-local-mongoose that handles this request so no need of using bcrypt. 
and it accepts 3 `cb(hashError,model,passwordError)`. So i decided to answer it incase  someone encounter same problem.

```
router.post("/enable2fa/:id", isVerified, function(req, res){
    if(req.isAuthenticated){
            User.findById(req.params.id, function(err,found){
            if(err){
                res.redirect("back")
                res.send('User not found with the proper ID')
            } else {
                if(req.body.accountPassword){
                    found.authenticate(req.body.accountPassword, function(err,model,passwordError){
                        if(passwordError){
                            console.log(err)
                            res.send('The given password is incorrect!!')
                        } else if(model) {
                            console.log(`correct password ${model}`)
                              *run other code stuff*
                            res.send('2fa enabled for this account')
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                     res.send('Please input your account password!!')
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        res.send('You are not authorized for this request')
    }

})
```